# save datagridview new column in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I make new column programmatically in c# windows application.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(string.Format("colmun{0}", i), string.Format("number {0}", i));
}
```

How I can save these columns in database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [create sql columns programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440738/create-sql-columns-programmatically)

Comment: Look first at [Sql Server Data Definition Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848799.aspx) then to ADO.NET classes like [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) and [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This might be the long way to do it, but...

```
string myColumnName = string.Empty;
string myDataType = string.Empty;

SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("put your database connection string here");
myConnection.Open(); //you might have to put this inside the foreach loop

foreach(DataGridViewColumn myColumn in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    myColumnName = myColumn.Name;
    myDataType = myColumn.ValueType.ToString();

if(myDataType.Contains("int"))
{
    myDataType = "int NULL";
}

if(myDataType.Contains("string"))
{
    myDataType = "varchar(255) NULL";
}

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("alter table [put your table name here] add [" + myColumnName + "] " + myDataType);
myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

myConnection.Close();
```

Comment: thanks. but it gives me this error : column names in each table must be unique. column name "ID" in table "mytablename" is specified more than once